# if(mysqli_num_rows) while(mysqli_fetch_assoc) cycle not posting correct value at first iteration, works for the next ones

Tags: php, mysql

My code is running a cycle that adds textareas where the user can input queries, which the div it is in also contains a dropdown with a list of servers available to run those queries in. At first it was working just fine for only the first iteration and not showing the list at all in the next dropdowns, but while I was messing with the code and pasted the query inside the cycle all dropdowns were filled but the server ID of the first textarea stopped being posted correctly, instead sending the value that's currently in the database. By other words it won't update properly.

```
<?php
if(mysqli_num_rows($result_query) > 0){ 
   while($rowq = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_query)){                        
     $sql_servers = "SELECT id, name, address FROM servers ORDER BY id ASC";
     $result_servers = mysqli_query($link, $sql_servers);
 ?>
     <table>
       <form name="formStep" method="post" action="">
       <br>
       <tr>
         <textarea class="form-control scrollabletextbox" id="query<?php echo $rowq['step']?>" name="query<?php echo $rowq['step']?>"><?php echo $rowq['query'];?></textarea>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td width="25%" style="vertical-align:middle;"><select id="server" name="server" class="form-control input-md">
         <?php
          if (mysqli_num_rows($result_servers) > 0) { 
            while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_servers)){ ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $rows["id"];?>" <?php if($rows['id']==$row_query2['id_server']) echo 'selected=\"selected\"' ?> ><?php echo $rows["name"];?></option>   
           <?php
           }
           }?>                      
           </select>
           </td>
           <td style="padding:10px;"><input type="submit" name="submit" formaction="save.php?i=4&id=<?php echo $id; ?>&s=<?php echo $rowq['step'];?>" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" value="<?php echo $lableSave; ?>"></td>
          </tr>
          <?php
           }
           }?>
          </form>  
         </table>
```

If I echo the server variable in the save.php it will not update for the new selected value in the dropdown, but it will work for all the subsequent iterations of the cycle.

Any way to solve this problem or the previous one before i started trying to hammer the code until it worked would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of making the same query over and over again inside the loop, just make it once before the loop and reuse the result.

Comment: that was what I did at first, but like I mentioned, only the first dropdown would be filled and the next ones would appear empty. pasting the query inside the cycle is not optimal, but was the way I found to make it fill all dropdowns

Comment: You should make the query before the loop and store the result in a variable: `$data = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);` and then use the `$data`-variable inside the loop. If you use a `while` loop on the database result directly inside the loop, then it will go through all the item once and the cursor will stay at the end for the next iterations.

Comment: I'm probably not doing it the right way, but I tried a couple different ways and it returns all dropdowns as empty. Could you please show an example for the loop? Thanks for the help so far. :)